# Estimation of some Integrals, which exceeded Wolfram Alpha's free computation time.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I want to have an upper bound for $$\int_1^\frac{1}{p}(1-sp)^\frac{\gamma}{p} \frac{1-\log(s)}{s}ds-\int_1^\infty e^{-\gamma s}\frac{1-\log(s)}{s}ds.$$ However, I could not compute either one of these integrals with wolfram Alpha. The bound can be as high as possible but it should be constant. Note that $p \in (0,1)$ and $\gamma \in (0,\infty)$. I do not need an actual antiderivative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that $1-x-e^{-x}$ has derivative $-(1-e^{-x})$, so it has a global maximum at $x=0$ and is decreasing for $x>0$.
Then

$$0<1-sp < e^{-sp}$$

and hence

$$(1-sp)^{1/p} < e^{-s} \implies (1-sp)^{\gamma/p} < e^{-\gamma \,s}.$$

Now, rewrite your expression as

$$
\underbrace{\int_1^\frac{1}{p}\,
\underbrace{\left((1-sp)^\frac{\gamma}{p} - e^{-\gamma\,s} \right)}_{<0}\frac{1-\log(s)}{s}\,ds}_{(\triangle)}
\quad
\underbrace{-
\int_{1/p}^\infty\,
e^{-\gamma s}\,\frac{1-\log(s)}{s}\,ds}_{(*)}.$$

We further expand $(*)$

$$
\underbrace{\int_{1/p}^\infty\,
e^{-\gamma s}\,\frac{\log(s)}{s}\,ds}_{>0}
\quad\underbrace{-
\int_{1/p}^\infty\,
e^{-\gamma s}\,\frac{1}{s}\,ds}_{<0}
$$

and hence need only consider the first term above.
We write

$$\int_{1/p}^\infty\,
e^{-\gamma s}\,\frac{\log(s)}{s}\,ds
<
\int_{1/p}^\infty\,
e^{-\gamma s}\,\log(s)\,ds
<
\int_{1/p}^\infty\,
e^{-\gamma s}\,s\,ds
=
\frac{(p+\gamma)\,e^{-\gamma/p}}{p\,\gamma^2}.
$$

It remains only to bound $(\triangle)$.
Write:

\begin{align}
(\triangle)
&=
\underbrace{\int_1^\frac{1}{p}\,
\left((1-sp)^\frac{\gamma}{p} - e^{-\gamma\,s} \right)\frac{1}s\,ds}_{<0}
\quad -
\int_1^\frac{1}{p}\,
\left((1-sp)^\frac{\gamma}{p} - e^{-\gamma\,s} \right)\frac{\log(s)}{s}\,ds
\\&<
\int_1^\frac{1}{p}\,
\left( e^{-\gamma\,s} - (1-sp)^\frac{\gamma}{p} \right)\frac{\log(s)}{s}\,ds
\\&<
\int_1^\frac{1}{p}\,
e^{-\gamma\,s}\,\frac{\log(s)}{s}\,ds
\\&<
\int_1^\frac{1}{p}\,
e^{-\gamma\,s}\,s\,ds
<
\int_0^\frac{1}{p}\,
e^{-\gamma\,s}\,s\,ds
=
\frac{p-(p+\gamma)\,e^{-\gamma/p}}{p\,\gamma^2}.
\end{align}

Combining the two bounds, we find that regardless of the value of $p$ your initial expression is less than $\gamma^{-2}$.